# Изменение блоков при адаптивной верстке

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть сайт (адаптивный). У меня есть на странице в блоке контента 3 блока друг за другом (по типу новость с кратким содержанием, по нажатии на которую кидает на другую страницу, где эта новость открывается в полном обьъеме).

Я хочу сделать в адаптивке, чтобы эти блоки находились в слайдере (который был бы просто по центру страницы), и он пролистывал сам новости, а при нажатии повторялось тоже самое, что и выше.

Было бы просто, если бы слайдер был отдельным блоком, который можно *none* на обычном расширении и *inline-block* на мобильной версии. Но как быть, если мне нужно им обернуть блоки? Тогда все содержимое тоже скроется при *none*.

Может быть, это делается с помощью js?

Comment: помнится когда только начинал, мы дублировали такие блоки. Один для декстопа, второй для мобилки, скрываем тот или другой. Сейчас конечно, я бы обернул блоки в контейнер слайдера сразу, но слайдер инициализировал только на маленьком экране. Например, в слайдере [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) есть `breakpoint` из коробки.

Comment: Или необходимо создать рядом такой слайдер с этими блоками внутри и скрыть его?

Comment: breakpoint это что-то вроде запуска слайдера, на каком-то расширении, без скрытия содержимого?

Comment: именно, посмотрите плагин, там есть блок `responsive desing`

Comment: Насколько я понял, это отображение количества слайдов внутри слайдера?

Comment: Да, задаем кол-во слайдов при нужном разрешение, а по умолчанию, ставим что бы слайдер не работал. Если немного повозится с настройками, можно добиться такого поведения.

Comment: спасибо большое, буду пытаться сделать, теперь хоть знаю куда копать

Comment: Я вас немного дезинформировал, по поводу использования `breakpoints` плагина в таком ключе, всё таки эта возможность работает по нисходящей, можно отключить слайдер для меньшего разрешения, но не для большего. Выкладываю рабочий пример немного в другом виде.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: можно извратиться и поставить элементам слайдера `visibility: hidden`, а на нужное расширении показать их. а чтоб его функционал не мешал, можно перекрыть подложкой и нужным индексом

Answer (score 2):

В данной ситуации можно использовать любой слайдер, который вам понравится.
Определяем размер экрана через `$(window).width()` и если размер нам подходит, инициализируем слайдер, например:

```
'use strict';
$(function () {
  var $window = $(window);
  var $slider = $('.js-slider');
  var hasInitSlider = false;

  function initSlider() {
    if ($window.width() < 400 && !hasInitSlider) {
      $slider.slick(); // слайдер slick
      hasInitSlider = true;
    } else if ($window.width() > 400 && hasInitSlider) {
      $slider.slick('unslick');
      hasInitSlider = false;
    }
  }

  initSlider();

  //дополнительно можно проверять на resize, но не обязательно.
  $window.on('resize', function () {
    initSlider();
  });
});
```

[Пример решения](http://codepen.io/olegatro/pen/GodWJL)

Пояснение:
1. Окно с блоками лучше расположить слева или справа, что бы удобнее можно было изменять размер окна. (кнопка `Change View`)
2. В примере используется шаблонизатор(`jade`) и препроцессор(`stylus`). Если с ними не знакомы, там есть кнопка `View Compiled`.